# No insight data been retrieved for archived or deleted ads

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve the insights metrics of the archived and deleted ads using the Facebook Graph Explorer with no success.

Query - GET

Version - V3.3,V3.2

URI -

```
act_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ads?fields=id,effective_status,updated_time,insights{spend,social_spend,relevance_score,reach,purchase_roas,place_page_name,outbound_clicks_ctr,outbound_clicks,objective,mobile_app_purchase_roas}&filtering=[{"field":"effective_status","operator":"IN","value":["ARCHIVED","DELETED"]}]
```

Output ( Insights data is missing )

```
{

 "data": [

    {
      "id": "1231231231231123",
      "effective_status": "ARCHIVED",
      "updated_time": "2019-03-30T21:53:50-0700"
    }
  ],

  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
      "after": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }

  }

}
```

According to the documentation, this should work but it doesn't.

Referance:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices/storing_adobjects?hc_location=ufi

Thank you!

Udi